# SwiftUI iOS14 GeometryReader Invalid frame dimension

Tags: swiftui, ios14, geometryreader

My GeometryReader was working fine in iOS13 but now in iOS14 i get a thread issue.

"Invalid frame dimension (negative or non-finite)."

I printed the size that the reader should give back and it looked fine.

The app is still basically working, but looks a bit weird, because there is some padding introduced.

Does anyone have any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Like the error says the value you're passing to the frame is negative of non-finite. Please share some code so we can have a look at your specific problem

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64543714/swiftui-behavior-of-frameheight-nil